# How to link Mapbox markers with checkbox inside a HTML table

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a Mapbox map , and at the moment my marker comes up on map load. But what I'm trying to do is to only display the marker when the user clicks the check box inside the table. I have tried several methods but has not worked out.

HTML TABLE

```
<tbody class="data">
  <tr > <td class="check"> <input type="checkbox"  class="remember"></td> </tr>   
</tbody>
```

Javascript for Mapbox

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZXNxdWlsYXgiLCJhIjoiY2tqd2ZyMXJsMGVqeDJ4cW8xcnRja2tqdiJ9.7z7Eyrj3iexJ9uDVYIT0yw';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/joel001/ckokqqll178jp17n7ju7plcmy',
  center: [115.83333, -32.01667],
  zoom: 11
});

map.on('load', function () {

  map.loadImage(
    'https://img.icons8.com/nolan/64/map-pin.png',
    function (error, image) {
      if (error) throw error;

      // Add the image to the map style.
      map.addImage('myimage', image);

      map.addSource('places', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': {
          'type': 'FeatureCollection',
          'features': [
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            {
              'type': 'Feature',
              'properties': {
                'title': 'My Marker'
              },
              'geometry': {
                'type': 'Point',
                'coordinates': [long, lat]
              }
            }


          ]
        }
      });



      // Add a layer showing the places.


      map.addLayer({
        'id': 'places',
        'type': 'symbol',
        'source': 'places',
        'layout': {
          'icon-image': 'myimage',
          'text-field': ['get', 'title'],
          'text-offset': [0, 1.55],
          'text-anchor': 'top'
        }


      });



      // When a click event occurs on a feature in the places layer, open a popup at the
      // location of the feature, with description HTML from its properties.
      map.on('click', 'places', function (e) {
        var coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
        var description = e.features[0].properties.description;

        // Ensure that if the map is zoomed out such that multiple
        // copies of the feature are visible, the popup appears
        // over the copy being pointed to.
        while (Math.abs(e.lngLat.lng - coordinates[0]) > 180) {
          coordinates[0] += e.lngLat.lng > coordinates[0] ? 360 : -360;
        }

        new mapboxgl.Popup()
          .setLngLat(coordinates)
          .setHTML(description)
          .addTo(map);
      });

      // Change the cursor to a pointer when the mouse is over the places layer.
      map.on('mouseenter', 'places', function () {
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
      });

      // Change it back to a pointer when it leaves.
      map.on('mouseleave', 'places', function () {
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
      });

    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A working solution by adding an EventListener on your checkbox and then play on mapbox source data by reassigning GeoJSON content

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Display a map on a webpage</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.2.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.2.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
  <style>
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #map { width: 100%; height: 400px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody class="data">
      <tr>
        <td class="check"> <input id="mycheckbox" type="checkbox" class="remember"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
  mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZXNxdWlsYXgiLCJhIjoiY2tqd2ZyMXJsMGVqeDJ4cW8xcnRja2tqdiJ9.7z7Eyrj3iexJ9uDVYIT0yw';
  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/joel001/ckokqqll178jp17n7ju7plcmy',
    center: [115.83333, -32.01667],
    zoom: 2
  });


  var long = 115.83333;
  var lat = -32.01667;

  map.on('load', function() {

    map.loadImage(
      'https://img.icons8.com/nolan/64/map-pin.png',
      function(error, image) {
        if (error) throw error;

        // Add the image to the map style.
        map.addImage('myimage', image);

        map.addSource('places', {
          'type': 'geojson',
          'data': {
            'type': 'FeatureCollection',
            'features': []
          }
        });

        // Add a layer showing the places.
        map.addLayer({
          'id': 'places',
          'type': 'symbol',
          'source': 'places',
          'layout': {
            'icon-image': 'myimage',
            'text-field': ['get', 'title'],
            'text-offset': [0, 1.55],
            'text-anchor': 'top'
          }
        });

        // When a click event occurs on a feature in the places layer, open a popup at the
        // location of the feature, with description HTML from its properties.
        map.on('click', 'places', function(e) {
          var coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
          var description = e.features[0].properties.description;

          // Ensure that if the map is zoomed out such that multiple
          // copies of the feature are visible, the popup appears
          // over the copy being pointed to.
          while (Math.abs(e.lngLat.lng - coordinates[0]) > 180) {
            coordinates[0] += e.lngLat.lng > coordinates[0] ? 360 : -360;
          }

          new mapboxgl.Popup()
            .setLngLat(coordinates)
            .setHTML(description)
            .addTo(map);
        });

        // Change the cursor to a pointer when the mouse is over the places layer.
        map.on('mouseenter', 'places', function() {
          map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
        });

        // Change it back to a pointer when it leaves.
        map.on('mouseleave', 'places', function() {
          map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
        });

        var checkbox = document.getElementById('mycheckbox');
        checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
          if (this.checked) {
            map.getSource('places').setData({
              'type': 'FeatureCollection',
              'features': [{
                'type': 'Feature',
                'properties': { 'title': 'My Marker' },
                'geometry': { 'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [long, lat] }
              }]
            });
          } else {
            map.getSource('places').setData({
              'type': 'FeatureCollection',
              'features': []
            });
          }
        });
      }
    );
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much man, i have tried so many things and this works perfectly. Thank you !!!!!!

Comment: Hey man just one trouble, I'm not able to show two markers at the same time when two check boxes are ticked? does it only support one marker? Thanksss

Comment: No. The issue is what you are asking is another thing... You want to be able to filter data based on multiple checkboxes. What I've done is showing how to show or hide one or more markers from one checkbox. You can have multiple markers in GeoJSON features from FeatureCollection.

Comment: See this official example https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-markers/. It seems to fit better than my answer your additional demand. Instead of playing with data source, it changes the style to display only the tickbox checked

Comment: ohhh im so sorry, i asked the question like that thinking its the same principle when 2 check boxes are involved. i actually have more than 2 check boxes.  So there is no way i can make this work for multiple markers? :(

Comment: Yes i was working with that mapbox example for 2 days . But i was struggling to apply it to my solution as its more of toggling a list.